# Error: Page crashed! at Page._onTargetCrashed PUPPETEER

Tags: web-scraping, browser, error-handling, crash, puppeteer

I'm having page crash error even after handling it via catch and using page.on(error). Please help me fix this error.

```
  // open the headless browser
  var browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, args: ['--disable-gpu','--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] });
  // Open a new page
  var page = await browser.newPage();
  var hsURL =highschoolURL.concat(hsList[i].trim()).concat("/academics");
  await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
  page.on('error', err=> {
    console.log('error happen at the page: ', err);
  });

  page.on('pageerror', pageerr=> {
    console.log('pageerror occurred: ', pageerr);
  })
  await page.goto(hsURL, {waitUntil : 'networkidle2'}).catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Answer (score 0):

the default *setDefaultNavigationTimeout* is 3000(3 seconds). You should not set *setDefaultNavigationTimeout* to 0 . Just set *setDefaultNavigationTimeout* to await **page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(3000);** or remove that sentences

Answer (score 0):

Error: Page crashed! at Page._onTargetCrashed can occur if there isn't enough memory for puppeteer to run.

Increasing the amount of memory available for puppeteer should help resolve this issue.